# how to duplicate items in a list in java

Tags: java, list

i have a list of dates id like to be able to duplicate them by X so specifically if my list reads A,B,C and X = 3 id like it to read A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C ive tried doing this through a loop but got stuck first with the list size always growing and then with putting the item in the right index again as the list keeps growing can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like you need to not modify your starting list, but make a new list for your results instead.

Comment: Create new list which will be filled X times with each item. Then either return that list or clear old one and replace its content with new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, it's probably easier to learn by seeing rather than by hearing explanations of what to do, so here's some simple working code:

```
public List<Date> repeat(List<Date> dates, int times)
{
    List<Date> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Date d : dates)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
            results.add(d.clone());
    }
    return results;
}
```

---

We make a new "results" list that we build up by iterating over the input list - for each item in the input list, we add that item to the results list a number of times. This makes the algorithm a lot simpler than trying to duplicate your items within the same list!

Note that we clone the date each time - otherwise we'll end up with a list containing sequences of elements that all point to the same actual `Date` object - not ideal in most cases.

---

You can use generics to make this method more reusable - ideally, we'd like this to work for all `Cloneable` objects, not just `Date`s:

```
public static <T extends Cloneable> List<T> repeat(List<T> in, int times)
{
    List<T> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T x : in)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
            results.add(x);
    }
    return results;
}
```

[Code demo (generics version)](https://ideone.com/so9lld).

Comment: That's awesome many thanks so tbh I was just shooting myself in the foot by trying to keep it in the original list

Comment: @martinseal1987 Exactly - there are algorithms that can easily be done ["in-place"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) - this just happens to not be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the solution in C# as I don't have a Java IDE on this computer, but its only a hair different than Java. The logic (and most of the code) is the same. Try this:

```
public static List<string> createList(List<string>originalList, int x)
{
    List<string> newList = new List<string>();
    foreach(string s in originalList)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            newList.Add(s);
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it'll work but I'm gonna give the points to the solution below as it's in java many thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score -1):

You need a linkedlist to add to it. Use this program to achieve the functionality.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LinkedList<String> al=new LinkedList<>();
        al.add("A");
        al.add("B");
        al.add("C");
        modify(al,4);

        System.out.println(al);
    }

    private static void modify(LinkedList<String> al, int X) {
        int size=al.size();
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            for(int i=1;i<X;i++)
            {
                al.add(X*j, al.get(X*j));
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need a `LinkedList`, any list will do when you're using this approach, although `LinkedList` has one advantage that you haven't mentioned. And you might want to add some explanation - it's not immediately clear what lines like `al.add(X*j, al.get(X*j))` do. Finally, clearing up your code might be a good idea - you're mixing brace styles and have a random comment.

Comment: My friend, I have used linked list as he wanted modifications in the same list and not asked for a new list. Insertion in between is always recommended over a linked list and not any other list. My aim was to use the same list to achieve the result. Please don't down vote if you are not sure of the reason.